# Output PHP conditional to string, remove last character

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements, substr

I am using wordpress's advanced custom fields, which uses the syntax `get_field('custom_field_name');` to pull custom fields from the database. in this case, I have a series of checkboxes, and I am using PHP to see if each one has been checked, and if so, it will spit out a string. Here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
    if(in_array('brand-id', get_field('type_of_work') )): echo "<a href='../../work/#brand-id'>Brand ID</a> |"; endif; echo " ";

    if(in_array('print', get_field('type_of_work') )): echo "<a href='../../work/#print'>Print</a> |"; endif; echo " ";

    if(in_array('books', get_field('type_of_work') )): echo "<a href='../../work/#books'>Books</a> |"; endif; echo " ";

    if(in_array('web', get_field('type_of_work') )): echo "<a href='../../work/#web'>Web</a> |"; endif; echo " "; 

    if(in_array('packaging', get_field('type_of_work') )): echo "<a href='../../work/#packaging'>Packaging</a> |"; endif; echo " ";

    if(in_array('exhibit', get_field('type_of_work') )): echo "<a href='../../work/#exhibit'>Exhibit</a> |"; endif; 

?>
```

What this is doing is saying, if this checkbox is checked, then spit out a link for that checkbox. As you can see, I am echoing a "|" after each link. The problem is that the last link is followed by a "|". I would like to remove the last "|" programmatically with PHP. Perhaps I can convert the whole thing to a string and then use `substr($string, 0, -1);`? Anny ideas how I would go about this?

Comment: Instead of echoing you could add them to an array then implode the array with | as the separator.

Comment: Im new to php, so Im not sure how to go about that....I do know that advanced custom fields can spit out an array using <?php the_field('type_of_work'); ?>

Comment: Do you need every field that is output from that array?

Comment: Yes, if the checkbox is checked on the backend, I need it to spit out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$links = array();

if(in_array('brand-id', get_field('type_of_work') )) $links[] = "<a href='../../work/#brand-id'>Brand ID</a>";
....

echo implode(" | ",$links);
```

Comment: I use this method quite a lot, when you need a separator between items.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string:

```
$checks = "";

if(in_array('brand-id', get_field('type_of_work') )):  $checks .= "<a href='../../work/#brand-id'>Brand ID</a> | "; endif;

if(in_array('brand-id', get_field('type_of_work') )):  $checks .= "<a href='../../work/#print'>Print</a> |"; endif;
```

Then: substr() on $checks: `echo substr($checks, 0, -2);`

Comment: yes, so for the next one, will it just add the new text to the variable set above, or will it replace it?

Comment: do you mind just adding a second line for another checkbox so I can see how the variable is built?

Comment: It will add if you concatenate: $checks .= "NEW_VALUE";

Comment: I see this also works great...Is @gunnx method a better practice? That is is it more efficient to implode versus substr?

Comment: I don't think there is much speed difference so its down to preference really.

Answer (score 0):

1. instead of echo-ing the text directly, concatenate it to a string variable
2. use `trim($string, '|')` to remove trailing pipe `|` ([manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php))

Comment: I like this idea... so how do I store it in a variable, and then let the next one add it to the same variable?

Comment: `if(condition1){ $string .='text1';} if(condition2){ $string .='text2';} ...`